# Should Zeke's herald be more of a mandatory item for supports since the recent Life Steal nerf.

Tags: league-of-legends

I realize that this item does not build from any GP/10 items and requires you to build a second kindle gem including the one you would normally build for your Shurelya's Reverie, but since the recent nerf to life steal items, I see this item becoming more popular on supports.

Answer (score 2):

I still this it's a situational item. Expensive as hell, it really only benefits that auto attacking champions on your team. Obviously if you're running Tristana, Renekton and Lee Sin (as an example), then yes, it's definitely something you should prioritize. However, items like Aegis and Reverie usually have more universal uses.

Despite support champions running the same basic GP/10 setup, there are times where it's good to deviate into items like will of the ancients, Zeke's or something else.

Comment: Starks does not exist anymore and has been reworked into Zeke's Herald.

Comment: Yep slight mistype, meant to say Zeke's there :)

Answer (score 0):

its a great item for supports to build but the downside is it is very expensive and since most supports do not have a steady income of gold you wont be seeing this item until lategame since it helps only the adcarry maybe top maybe jungle, but adcarry the most it will not be as popular as shurelya's crown or the locket